# Simple Sitemap using default instead of website URL

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap/

I am using above module

**abc.com/admin/config/search/simplesitemap**

[image]

When I am generating sitemap via UI or `drush simple_sitemap-generate` command.

It is using

```
 <url>
  <loc>http://default/ja</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://default/ja"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="http://default/ja"/>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.0</priority>
 </url>
```

On my Website I am using only English language. Other languages are configured. But not using that.

How to remove those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happenes when generating the sitemap via CLI cron without `--uri` parameter. Either pass the Domain into the CLI

```
drush --uri=https://www.example.com simple-sitemap:generate
```

or use the web interface to generate the sitemap.